# Who will be target of Kalki?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, kalki

By seeing today's world scenario, who do you think, will be target of Kalki.
Because even today, we can see the different people having different paths.
Is there, any reference, who will be actually target. (Off course those will be adharmi people, but any specific detail?)

Comment: Did you read the Kalki purana?

Comment: @Wikash_ why do you want to know?

Comment: No avatar can even move a finger without Parabrahman willing it....so basically, you will know just in time....

Answer (score 3):

As per [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa): Skandha 12: Adhyay 2](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/2/19-20/):

> विचरन्नाशुना क्षौण्यां हयेनाप्रतिमद्युति: ।
>
> नृपलिङ्गच्छदो दस्यून्कोटिशो निहनिष्यति ॥ २० ॥
>
> Displaying His unequaled effulgence and riding with great speed, He will kill by the millions those thieves who have dared dress as kings.

Comment: So he won't be having a single target, but a collection of targets that needs killing.

Comment: Politicians seems the target

Answer (score 3):

The objective role and activities of "kalki" a avatara of Lord Vishnu that has yet to come is described in various Hinduism scriptures like puranas and itihasa. 
First of all let us see what Mahabharata is saying about who will be target of Kalki. It

Is mentioned in [**Mahabharata**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03190.htm) -Vana Parva-Chapter 191 by sage Markandeya  that  Kalki will destroy  foreigners as well as  dacoits and thieves and bandits.

> ततस्चोररक्षयं कृत्वा द्विजेभ्य: पृथिवीमिमाम् |
>  वाजिमेधे महायज्ञे
>   विधिवत कल्पयिष्यति || 1 ||
>
> Markandeya continued, 'Having exterminated the thieves and robbers,
>   Kalki will, at a great Horse-sacrifice, duly give away this earth to
>   the Brahmanas, and having established anew the blessed rectitude
>   ordained by the Self-create, Kalki, of sacred deeds and illustrious
>   reputation, will enter a delightful forest, and the people of this
>   earth will imitate his conduct

---

**Matysa Purana - Chapter 273.27**  is telling us that at the time of Kalki avatara Yavanas will dwell here for sake of profit. All types of people will steadily detroit by following contrary way of life i.e. they will be adharmik. Kings will be untruthful and will be greedy. All these type of people who are following adharmik way , unrighteous way will be overpowered and will be killed by Kalki, no matter they are Mlecchas or Aryas. And only good people will remain.

> कल्किनानुहता: सर्वे आर्या म्लेच्छाच्श्र सर्वश: |
>  अधार्मिकाच्श्र
>   येSत्यर्थ पाषण्डाश्चैव सर्वश: ||
>
> The people will steadily deteriorate by adopting a contrary course of
>   life , so along the kings will be greedy and speakers of untruth. All
>   will be overpowered (killed) everywhere by Kalki whether they be Aryas
>   or Mlecchas.
>   [image]

---

The Bhagavata Purana Skanda 10-Chapter 40- Verse 22 is suggesting that the target ogf  Lord Kalki will  also be meat eaters people who will be posing themselves as kings.

> नमो बुद्धाय शुद्धाय दैत्यदानवमोहिने ।
>  म्‍लेच्छप्रायक्षत्रहन्त्रे
>   नमस्ते कल्किरूपिणे ॥[**SB 10.40.22**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/40/22/)  ॥
>
> namo buddhāya śuddhāya daitya-dānava-mohine
>   mleccha-prāya-kṣatra-hantre namas te kalki-rūpiṇe
>
> Obeisances to Your form as the faultless Lord Buddha, who will
>   bewilder the Daityas and Dānavas, and to Lord Kalki, the annihilator
>   of the meat-eaters posing as kings.

we find here  mentioning that Lord Kalki will destroy the meat eater kings of the earth. i.e. we can say that the meaning of this is that he will end the rulers who will have  indulged themselves in materialistic things.etc. and falsely considering themselves as kings and rulers.

---

So in conclusion Kalki would rid the earth of the unrighteous and implant dharma again and his target will be unrighteous people including people from outside of bharata as well as insiders i.e. Aryas and Mlecchas. All the people who are unrighteous including kings and thieves and bandits etc.

Comment: Well right now more indians are living abroad in western countries then westerners in india :p

Comment: "meat-eaters posing as kings" - you need to find a better translation. The word used is "mleccha." It doesn't translate to "meat-eaters." Kshatriya kings are allowed to hunt and eat meat. ISKCON translations seem to convert gullible readers to vegetarians with wrong and misleading interpretations like this.

Comment: What is the correct translation of mleccha.

Answer (score 2):

According to Kalki Purana, Kalki Avatara will kill Buddhists, Mlecchas and Yavanas.

The [introduction of the Purana](http://www.astrojyoti.com/kalkipurana.htm) summarizes this as follows:

> Among the upa-puranas or sub Puranas, the Kalki Purana is most sacred
>   and widely respected. **At the end of Kah-yuga, the Supreme Lord,
>   Hari, will incarnate as Lord Kalki and kill all the mlecchas, yavanas,
>   atheists, and Buddhists of the world that defy the Vedic authority.**
>   The pastimes of Lord Kalki are the subject matter of this literature,
>   which is presented in story form. Exalted personalities can see
>   everything, past, present, and future. For this reason, there is no
>   fault in narrating these future events as if they had already
>   occurred. The Kalki Purana consists of thirty-five chapters.

And, we can find the details of these battles against the Buddhists in subsequent chapters of the Purana.

For e.g. [Chapter 14](http://www.astrojyoti.com/kalkipurana3.htm) states:

> **Lord Kalki Conquers the Buddhists Who Opposed Him**
>
> Text 1
>
> Suta GosvamI said: Just as a lion, the king of the jungle, attacks a
>   female elephant, Lord Kalki, the life and soul of all living entities,
>   attacked the army of Buddhists.
>
> Texts 2-3
>
> **Thereafter, a fierce battle took place between the Buddhists and Lord
>   Kalki** When the Buddhists became disheartened and began fleeing from
>   the battle, Lord Kalki, acting as the commander-in-chief of His army,
>   addressed the opposing warriors, who were injured in the battle, whose
>   garments and armor were scattered here and there, whose hair had
>   become loosened, and who were screaming loudly in pain: О Buddhists,
>   do not run away from the battlefield. Stay here and fight to the best
>   of your ability so that you will avoid the shame of being considered
>   cowards.
>
> Although Jina had been injured, he became enraged upon hearing Lord
>   Kalki’s taunting words. After picking up his sword and shield, he
>   rushed at Lord Kalki, who was sitting on His horse. In the duel that
>   ensued, both fought with great enthusiasm so that even the demigods,
>   who were watching from the heavens, became surprised to witness Jina’s
>   skill in fighting.
>
> Text 6
>
> The greatly powerful Jina pierced Kalki’s horse with his trident and
>   then made the Lord fall unconscious by his onslaught of arrows. At
>   this, the wicked Jina attempted to capture Lord Kalki, but was unable
>   to pick Him up.
>
> Text 7
>
> Lord Kalki had become so heavy that Jina could not even move Him and
>   this fueled his rage. Being unable to take Lord Kalki prisoner, Jma
>   finally took His crown and weapons and fled.
>
> ---
>
> Text 12
>
> Indeed, the heavy breathing of Lord Kalki’s horse caused many opposing
>   soldiers to fly into the sky and then fall down at distant places.
>   Some of them fell upon the horses and chariots as they descended onto
>   the battlefield.
>
> Text 13
>
> **Within a short period of time, Gargya and his associates killed six
>   thousand Buddhist warriors. Bhargya killed ten million enemy soldiers
>   with the help of his army, and Visala killed twenty-five thousand.**

And, from [Chapter 16](http://www.astrojyoti.com/kalkipurana4.htm), we have:

> Text 1
>
> Suta GosvamI said. **After killing the Buddhists and mlecchas of
>   Kikatapura, Lord Kalki took their wealth and returned to His capital,
>   along with His vast army.**
>
> Text 2
>
> Lord Kalki, the unhmitedly powerful protector of religious principles,
>   next went to Cakratlrtha and took a ritualistic bath, according to
>   prescribed procedure.

Comment: I don't think atheists and Buddhists are directly mentioned. This is how Srila Prabhupada choose to translate/interpret it. Corruption in my view.

Comment: Well Buddhists and Mlecchas are mentioned in the chapters I have quoted .. @Viper91

Comment: @Viper91 The [words used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJkKs.png) are: 1) bauddha 2) [pāṣaṇḍa](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=ia&tran_input=pASaNDa&direct=se&anz=100) (heterodox/heretical) 3) mleccha

Comment: Yes so Buddhists and Mlecchas were not inserted by the translator. That's what I meant. @Viper91

Comment: Please note that this about Buddhists who DEFY the Vedic authority. Not every buddhist will be killed.

Comment: "Please note that this about Buddhists who DEFY the Vedic authority. Not every Buddhist will be killed." - where did you read this exception?! Buddhists don't accept the authority of the Vedas. @Wikash

Comment: @Wikash_ It's "Buddhists" over 400,000 years in the future (and with really obvious supernatural stuff like the giant Rakshasa lady in the sky). No one really knows what they believe.

Comment: @SayNoToCensorship Actually the Buddhist's God-like figure merges with Kalki, so they are actually right to some extent in their worship if I remember correctly. Got to love Hinduism ardently sticking to its balanced outlook on villains. Probably why I believe in it so much, that's a weird thing for any human group to be completely consistent about.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm

This is how Kali will be born

> And commissioned by Time, a Brahmana of the name of Kalki will take his birth. And he will glorify Vishnu and possess great energy, great intelligence, and great prowess. And he will take his birth in a town of the name of Sambhala in an auspicious Brahmana family. And vehicles and weapons, and warriors and arms, and coats of mail will be at his disposal as soon as he will think of them. **And he will be the king of kings, and ever victorious with the strength of virtue. And he will restore order and peace** in this world crowded with creatures and contradictory in its course. **And that blazing Brahmana of mighty intellect, having appeared, will destroy all things. And he will be the Destroyer of all, and will inaugurate a new Yuga.** And surrounded by the Brahmanas, that Brahmana will exterminate all the **mlecchas wherever those low and despicable persons** may take refuge."

Kalki will conduct a horse-sacrifice

> "Markandeya continued, 'Having exterminated the thieves and robbers, Kalki will, at a great Horse-sacrifice, duly give away this earth to the Brahmanas, and having established anew the blessed rectitude ordained by the Self-create, Kalki, of sacred deeds and illustrious reputation, will enter a delightful forest, and the people of this earth will imitate his conduct, and when the Brahmanas will have exterminated the **thieves and robbers**, there will be prosperity everywhere (on earth). And as the countries of the earth will one after another be subjugated, that tiger among Brahmanas, Kalki, having placed deer skins and lances and tridents there, will roam over the earth, adored by foremost Brahmanas and showing his regard for them and engaged all the while in **slaughtering thieves and robbers. And he will exterminate the thieves and robbers** amid heart-rending cries of 'Oh, father--' 'Oh, mother!--'O son!' and the like, and O Bharata, when sin will thus have been rooted out and virtue will flourish on arrival of the Krita age, men will once more betake themselves to the practice of religious rites.

The goal of Kalki is that he should restore peace and order to earth and inagurate a new yuga, the Satya yuga (age of truth) and he will continue to subjugate countries and kill the unrighteous people who are mlecchas wherever those low and despicable persons take refuge. He will later conduct horse-sacrifice in which, he will give away the entire earth to brahmanas. He will later roam around the earth and exterminate the thieves and robbers.